# A question about a tight sequence of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Q) Suppose $Y_n\geq 0$, $EY_{n}^{\alpha}\rightarrow 1$ and $EY_n^{\beta}\rightarrow 1$ for some $0<\alpha<\beta$. Show that $Y_n\rightarrow 1$ in probability. It has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151328/convergence-in-probability-and-or-weak-convergence) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386119/ey-n-alpha-to-1-and-e-y-n-beta-to-1-implies-y-n-to-1-in-probabiltiy) but wanted to check if I can apply and understand tightness.

If there is a $\phi$, s.t. $\phi(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$ and $\text{sup}_n\int \phi(x)dF_n(x)<\infty$, then $F_n$ is tight. Does $EY_n^{\alpha}\rightarrow 1\implies$ that the sequence is tight? Firstly, I don't know if $Y_n^{\alpha}(w)\rightarrow \infty$ as $|w|\rightarrow \infty$ and even if it does, not sure how that implies $EY_n^{\alpha}\leq C<\infty$ and what stops $EY_n^{\alpha}$ from blowing up for small $n$?

But if the sequence is tight, rest falls in place. Let $F_{n_k}\implies F$ and since the sequence is tight, $F$ is the distribution function of some random variable Y. There is a theorem that says if $g,h$ are continuous, $|h(x)|/g(x)\rightarrow 0 \text{ as } |x|\rightarrow \infty, F_n\implies F \text{ and } \int g(x)dF_n(x)\leq C< \infty$, then $\int h(x)dF_n(x)\rightarrow \int h(x)dF(x)$. Thus $EY_{n_k}^{\alpha}\rightarrow EY^{\alpha}=1$. By squeezing, $EY^{\gamma} = 1 = (EY^{\alpha})^{\gamma/\alpha}$ for $\gamma \in (\alpha,\beta)$. Thus for the function $f(x) = x^{\gamma/\alpha}$, we have an equality in Jensen's and thus $Y^{\alpha}=EY^{\alpha}=1$. $F_{n_k}\implies F$ and $Y=1=\text{ constant}$ implies $Y_n$ converges to $1$ in probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y_n \geq 0$ and $EY_n^{\alpha} \to 1$ for some $\alpha >0$ implies that $\{Y_n\}$ is tight: there is a constant $C$ such that $EY_n^{\alpha} \leq C$ for all $n$. By Chebychev's inequality we get $P(Y_n >M)=P(Y_n^{\alpha} >M^{\alpha}) \leq \frac {EY_n^{\alpha}} {M^{\alpha}} \leq \frac C {M^{\alpha}}$. Given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $M$ such that $\frac C {M^{\alpha}} <\epsilon$ and this makes $P(Y_n >M)<\epsilon$ for all $n$.

Comment: May I know why $\exists C$ s.t. $EY_n^{\alpha}\leq C$ for all n?

Comment: @manifolded Any convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded.

Comment: I see, thanks. Also, for tightness, how do we know that $P(Y_n<-M)$ is also small?

Comment: @manifolded You are taking $Y_n \geq 0$ so $P(Y_n <-M)=0$.

Comment: Ahh yes, missed that, sorry.